# Error in fill background at a cont plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have this pgplot with const graphs. The idea is that the first area at NW (which is actually the background) is completely green. Then the second area should be blue and the third one white. As you can see there is some noise in the filling that uses the background color green the blue area... I do not see what might be happening. I would appreciate any help!

I add below the figure and the code I am using.
[image]

```
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.6\linewidth} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=1.5,xmin=0.650756396219793
,xmax=1.53525871598697,
axis background/.style={fill=green},xlabel=$y$, ylabel=$d$]

\addplot
    [const plot,fill=blue,draw=black] 
coordinates%30pp
{
(0.650756396219793,0.301507537688442)
(0.662255930630742, 0.316582914572864)
(0.673958673634702, 0.324120603015075)
(0.685868216136382, 0.339195979899498)
(0.697988212495470, 0.361809045226131)
(0.710322381647943, 0.369346733668342)
(0.722874508247201, 0.391959798994975)
(0.735648443825360, 0.422110552763819)
(0.748648107975067, 0.444723618090452)
(0.761877489552200, 0.467336683417085)
(0.775340647899819, 0.497487437185930)
(0.789041714093750, 0.527638190954774)
(0.802984892210175, 0.550251256281407)
(0.817174460615623, 0.580402010050251)
(0.831614773279756, 0.618090452261307)
(0.846310261111356, 0.648241206030151)
(0.861265433317920, 0.685929648241206)
(0.876484878789271, 0.723618090452261)
(0.891973267505638, 0.761306532663317)
(0.907735351970595, 0.806532663316583)
(0.923775968669344, 0.844221105527638)
(0.940100039552749, 0.889447236180905)
(0.956712573547606, 0.934673366834171)
(0.973618668093594, 0.979899497487437)
(0.990823510707393, 1.01758793969849)
(1.00833238057443,  1.07035175879397)
(1.02615065016878,  1.11557788944724)
(1.04428378690164,  1.16080402010050)
(1.06273735479898,  1.20603015075377)
(1.08151701620885,  1.25879396984925)
(1.10062853353878,  1.31155778894472)
(1.12007777102400,  1.37185929648241)
(1.13987069652677,  1.42462311557789)
(1.16001338336763,  1.48492462311558)
(1.18051201218893,  1.50000000000000)
(1.20137287285133,  1.60000000000000)
(1.22260236636378,  1.50000000000000)
(1.24420700684765,  1.50000000000000)
(1.26619342353553,  1.50000000000000)
(1.28856836280535,  1.50000000000000)
(1.31133869025048,  1.50000000000000)
(1.33451139278639,  1.50000000000000)
(1.35809358079453,  1.50000000000000)
(1.38209249030407,  1.50000000000000)
(1.40651548521229,  1.50000000000000)
(1.43137005954408,  1.50000000000000)
(1.45666383975146,  1.50000000000000)
(1.48240458705369,  1.50000000000000)
(1.50860019981877,  1.50000000000000)
(1.53525871598697,  1.50000000000000)
};
    \closedcycle;
     \addplot
[const plot,fill=white,draw=black] 
coordinates%base 0.293969849246231)
{
(0.650756396219793,0.301507537688442)
(0.662255930630742, 0.309045226130653)
(0.673958673634702, 0.316582914572864)
(0.685868216136382, 0.324120603015075)
(0.697988212495470, 0.331658291457286)
(0.710322381647943, 0.331658291457286)
(0.722874508247201, 0.339195979899498)
(0.735648443825360, 0.346733668341709)
(0.748648107975067, 0.346733668341709)
(0.761877489552200, 0.361809045226131)
(0.775340647899819, 0.376884422110553)
(0.789041714093750, 0.399497487437186)
(0.802984892210175, 0.414572864321608)
(0.817174460615623, 0.437185929648241)
(0.831614773279756, 0.459798994974874)
(0.846310261111356, 0.482412060301508)
(0.861265433317920, 0.512562814070352)
(0.876484878789271, 0.535175879396985)
(0.891973267505638, 0.565326633165829)
(0.907735351970595, 0.595477386934673)
(0.923775968669344, 0.633165829145729)
(0.940100039552749, 0.663316582914573)
(0.956712573547606, 0.701005025125628)
(0.973618668093594, 0.738693467336683)
(0.990823510707393, 0.776381909547739)
(1.00833238057443,  0.814070351758794)
(1.02615065016878,  0.859296482412060)
(1.04428378690164,  0.904522613065327)
(1.06273735479898,  0.949748743718593)
(1.08151701620885,  1.00251256281407)
(1.10062853353878,  1.05527638190955)
(1.12007777102400,  1.10804020100503)
(1.13987069652677,  1.16080402010050)
(1.16001338336763,  1.22110552763819)
(1.18051201218893,  1.28894472361809)
(1.20137287285133,  1.34924623115578)
(1.22260236636378,  1.41708542713568)
(1.24420700684765,  1.49246231155779)
(1.26619342353553,  1.50000000000000)
(1.28856836280535,  1.50000000000000)
(1.31133869025048,  1.50000000000000)
(1.33451139278639,  1.50000000000000)
(1.35809358079453,  1.50000000000000)
(1.38209249030407,  1.50000000000000)
(1.40651548521229,  1.50000000000000)
(1.43137005954408,  1.50000000000000)
(1.45666383975146,  1.50000000000000)
(1.48240458705369,  1.50000000000000)
(1.50860019981877,  1.50000000000000)
(1.53525871598697,  1.50000000000000)
} 
    \closedcycle;
    \node at (axis cs:0.8,1) 
            {\large \textcolor{black}{$z'=1$}};
    \node at (axis cs:1.3,0.5) 
            {\large \textcolor{black}{$z'=0$ }};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually produces an error when compiled. There are other errors as well, which you can see from the small red box with the number 13, right next to the recompile button. Errors should always be fixed if they appear (click on the 13 for more info), otherwise you can't rely on the output.

That said, you have simply forgotten to remove a `;` after the closing `}` of the coordinate list of the first plot, so you have

```
};  %<--- this semicolon must be removed
    \closedcycle;
```

Remove the semicolon and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It completely solved the problem! Now the weird triangle disappeared!!! Thanks!